# Display Suite vs. EVA for displaying a view as field

Tags: views, 8, entities, display-suite

I want to display a specific view as a field in nodes. It’s the same view for all nodes of this type, making use of the contextual filter "Content ID from URL".

I found two solutions using contributed modules:

- [**EVA: Entity Views Attachment**](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva): it’s specifically for this use case
  (there is also [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield), but that’s still in alpha)
- [**Display Suite**](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds): it’s not its primary use case, but makes it possible by adding a "block field", where you can select the block generated by the view

Assuming that Display Suite is installed anyway (installing it just for this use case would be overkill, I guess), **is one solution better than the other?** Both seem to work fine, but I’m thinking of possible issues I can’t foresee now, like performance impact or compatibility with the Drupal ecosystem.

Comment: If it is the same view block on every full view of a node type, you don't need any module at all, just place the block and limit visibility of the block to the node type. You only need a module if you want to place the view block _in between_ node fields. If that's the case, I agree with 4k4 (EVA for sitebuilders, Viewsreference for editors)

Comment: @Hudri: Yes, the requirement is that the view can be used as field (so it can be moved under "Manage display").

Comment: @unor you can use `Viewfield` for what you need. See my steps to add it as it is quite simple. We have been using it for multiple views.

Comment: As mentioned below, the two options are [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) and [Views Reference Field](http://drupal.org/project/viewsreference).  However, they should be merged as per [Merge the Views Reference Field and Viewfield modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield/issues/1299222).  That's a better long-term plan.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best contender for EVA is Views Reference Field:

- [**EVA: Entity Views Attachment**](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)
- [**Views Reference Field**](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference)

Both have stable releases. Main difference is the workflow. EVA is perfect if you want to impress your co-workers with the ability to attach a View to a content type like magic. Views Reference Field gives content editors the power to add Views to content themselves. Both modules don't need a block display, EVA provides its own and Views Reference Field can use any display type.

Comment: For paragraphs, we actually use https://www.drupal.org/project/block_field, which has the benefit that you can also use the same pattern for any block, things like forms and so on. And while the UX is not very good *yet*, there is I think more potential for improvements because you have the block configuration form, can use plugin contexts and so on.

Comment: In case there is a misunderstanding: the solution I meant using Display Suite doesn’t add the blocks to the block layout (at `/admin/structure/block`). The blocks have to exist, but you don’t have to place them (i.e., creating a block display in Views is sufficient).

Comment: Yes, but you have them in the select list when you place a block. I think Views Reference Field is the more flexible solution, because you can choose any Views display not only blocks.

Comment: @Berdir, I removed my comment about not using blocks in fields, there are many valid use cases. For Views I think you don't need this anymore, now that these two great modules are available.

Answer (score 2):

We have found [viewfield 8.x-3.0-alpha2](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield/releases/8.x-3.0-alpha2) to be pretty stable even in `alpha`. Based on your description, here is how you can use it.

1. Add field where `type = viewfield`
2. select a view to be added to the content type.
3. if you are wanting to use the `node id` as a filter, you need to set the filter on the field settings. It allows you to do use all the tokens, even custom one. In your case it should be `[node:id]`. I believe it would be under `Arguments to be passed to the display`
4. Under `Manage Display` for the content type, ensure it is enabled and in the location you need it to be.
5. the `viewfield` comes with two twig templates that you can override as needed with relate `template_preprocess_viewfield()` and `template_preprocess_viewfield_item()` hooks.

Considerations:

1. Since it is a field on the content type, remember to add the field to either the twig template or display suite view so that it displays on the screen.
2. Views have different displays so when you select what View to add to the field, remember to select the display you need. For example, `master,`block`,`page`, etc. can all be selected.
3. You can reuse the field on multiple content types. Just remember to check that all the important field settings are set such as `[node:nid]` as a filter, the View display is enabled, and the correct view is selected.