# How to resolve lazy_builder error?

Tags: views, 8, entities

We have a field that is an Entity Reference to Blocks. In our situation, this field is referencing a View block. We are able to add this field on the content type and node properly, but when the page renders there is the following error message. We set this up using steps from [Drupal 8: How to Reference a Views' Block Display from a Field](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/drupal-8-how-reference-views-block-display-field/).

> Uncaught PHP Exception DomainException: "When a #lazy_builder callback is specified, no properties can exist; all properties must be generated by the #lazy_builder callback. You specified the following properties: #attached." at /mnt/www/html/netscout/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php line 333

How would we resolve this issue?

What we have tried:

1. [DomainException with #lazy_builder and ['#cache']['keys']](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2752889), but this did not have anything that helped because we do not load the block by using `#lazy_builder`
2. We tried updating our modules, but still get the error message
3. Tried removing the removing the block reference, but then we were not able to add the view block to the page.

We are using Drupal v8.5.3.

Comment: Drupal puts each block in a lazybuilder by default. The main use case for blocks is not to be referenced in an entity and probably there are no tests that check for regressions. Since the linked blog post a lot has changed and now there are better solutions, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261509/display-suite-vs-eva-for-displaying-a-view-as-field

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Entity Reference to Block, we went with using [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) module. It has worked as expected with and without exposed filters.